# ActionBarSherlock. homeAsUpIndicator - selector

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have the problem to customize the back arrow.

Here is my theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_white_my</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_white_my</item>
</style>
```

Here is selector - abs__ic_ab_back_white_my:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_white_default"
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"/>
<item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_white_pressed"
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_white_pressed"
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_white_default"/>    </selector>
```

Selector on the arrow does not work(It works on the ImageButton). Arrow always - abs__ic_ab_back_white_default

Comment: You are using your theme in manifest?

Comment: Yes. Icon arrow changed. And arrow always - abs__ic_ab_back_white_default.

Answer (score 1):

It works on a device with android version 4.3